# C++ Builder idFTP: Ошибка Unresolved External

Tags: c++, c++builder, indy

Создаю консольное приложение, передающее файл на ftp сервер.
При объявлении `idFTP`:

```
TIdFTP *idFTP = new TIdFTP(NULL);
```

выдает ошибку:

> Unresolved External

Comment: Недостаточно деталей что б сделать вывод. Попробуте переустановить среду. Без деталей больше нечего добавить.

Comment: А поисковик по ключевым словам кажется что-то находит https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122864/linker-error-unresolved-external-c-builder-6-0

Comment: @VTT борланд в некоторорых местах и правда глючит, скорее всего нужно добавить в вопрос больше деталей - сам символ, версии... тогда можно что-то конкретное ответить.

Comment: Как вариант - на с++ для фтп куча либ. Выбирайте любую другую. Indy не единственная, и не самая удобная. Даже WINAPI (Wininet) позволяет работать с фтп. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259166/good-free-ftp-client-library-for-windows-c-commercial-apps

Comment: wininet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988305/c-uploading-to-an-ftp-server-with-wininet